Ethernet is lost after apache benchmark with number a high number of open files
I have made an apache benchmark with using
sudo prlimit --pid=$$ --nofile=65536
ab -k -n 100000 -c 10000 https://example.com

but after lots of error that the bench gave I am now unable to even browse a single page using browser with the interface.
Wifi works great but the cabled ethernet which I had run the commands through stopped working. What should I do to get cabled ethernet working again?
Thank you in advance.
